# Preload image when clicking link & follow link after preload in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my app using Ionic Framework, on `event-detail.html`, I have this:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{event.name}}">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <p>
      {{event.name}}
    </p>
      <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/event-desc/{{event.ID}}">About</a><br /><br />
      <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/event-schedule/{{event.ID}}">Schedule</a>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

On `event-schedule.html`, there's an `ng-repeat`showing some images which are loaded from an external URL:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="s in schedule" ...>
<img width="100%" ng-src="{{s.mainImageUrl.EN}}">
...
</div>
```

This works fine, but sometimes there are around 8 images to show (i.e. to download).

Is it possible to preload the images *before* the transition effect and the next page is shown?

So basically, I'm looking for a way that when I press the link on `event-detail.html` , a loading spinners shows. When the images are loaded, the spinner disappears and the user is taken to `event-schedule.html`.

I'm new to Angular so any help is much appreciated!